# Induction in Coq on a tree structure

Tags: coq

This is a really elementary question, and I apologize, but I've been trying to use Coq to prove the following theorem, and just can't seem to figure out how to do it.

```
(* Binary tree definition. *)
Inductive btree : Type := 
  | EmptyTree
  | Node : btree -> btree -> btree.
(* Checks if two trees are equal. *)

Fixpoint isEqual (tree1 : btree) (tree2 : btree) : bool :=
  match tree1, tree2 with
    | EmptyTree, EmptyTree => true
    | EmptyTree, _ => false
    | _, EmptyTree => false
    | Node n11 n12, Node n21 n22 => (andb (isEqual n11 n21) (isEqual n12 n22))
end.

Lemma isEqual_implies_equal : forall tree1 tree2 : btree, 
(isEqual tree1 tree2) = true -> tree1 = tree2.
```

What I have been trying to do is apply induction on tree1 followed by tree2, but this doesn't really work correctly. It seems I need to apply induction to both simultaneously, but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to prove this using simple induction

```
Require Import Bool. (* Sorry! Forgot to add that the first time *)

Lemma isEqual_implies_equal : forall tree1 tree2 : btree, 
(isEqual tree1 tree2) = true -> tree1 = tree2.
  induction tree1, tree2; intuition eauto.
  inversion H.
  inversion H.
  apply andb_true_iff in H.
  intuition eauto; fold isEqual in *.
  apply IHtree1_1 in H0.
  apply IHtree1_2 in H1.
  congruence.
Qed.

(* An automated version *)
Lemma isEqual_implies_equal' : forall tree1 tree2 : btree, 
(isEqual tree1 tree2) = true -> tree1 = tree2.
  induction tree1, tree2; intuition; simpl in *;
  repeat match goal with
            | [ H : false = true |- _ ]   => inversion H
            | [ H : (_ && _) = true |- _] => apply andb_true_iff in H; intuition
            | [ IH : context[ _ = _ -> _], 
                H : _ = _ |- _]           => apply IH in H
         end; congruence.
  Qed.
```

By applying `induction` before `intros` our inductive hypothesis is polymorphic over `tree2` which allows us to use it in the final case.

Comment: Cool, thanks, that basically worked for me, but I had to make a few tweaks. First is that I didn't have andb_true_iff defined--I'm guessing this is in some library but I got the gist and made my own theorems for it (see above). I guess the most important question I can ask is this: why can I use IHtree1_1 and IHtree1_2 when they both refer to tree2 and not something like tree2_1 or (Node tree2_1 tree2_2) or something like that? I feel like the answer is going to be wrapped up in your phrase "polymorphic over tree2 which allows us to use it in the final case". So is tree2 not defined?

Comment: Cool. Require Import Bool. did the trick. I'm really, really new to Coq (you may have gathered), so things like this that should be obvious aren't yet.

Comment: @quadelirus Nope that one was my fault :) I just copied and pasted from emacs without realizing my import was at the top